# What is the meaning of "all the way up" , and what is the function of "up" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Peter was the smartest kid ***all the way up*** until the fifth grade.

What is the meaning of "all the way up" , and what is the function of "up" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`All the way` means "the whole time" (or "the whole distance or journey").

Up refers here to the idea that as you go to school, you move "upwards" trough the grades.

So "all the way up until fifth grade" means he was the smartest kid from the moment he started school until he had "moved upwards" to the fifth grade.

The use of "up" in a temporal sense is not uncommon - we seems to like to think as the passing of time as something that moves in an upward direction. We grow "up", for example, as we get older - or at least, that is what we are expected to do. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Although **all the way"** was explained in other answers already, I would like to discuss **"up until"** a little, along with its function (part of speech).

To understand the phrase "all the way up until", you should regroup the words into "all the way" and "up until", like this:

> *Peter was the smartest kid **[all the way] [up until]** the fifth grade.*

You could ditch "all the way" out and/or replace "up until" by "until" and the sentence will still have roughly the same meaning.

> *Peter was the smartest kid **all the way until** the fifth grade.*
>   *Peter was the smartest kid **up until** the fifth grade.*
>   *Peter was the smartest kid **until** the fifth grade.*

The phrase "up until" has a similar meaning to "until". In Macmillan Dictionary, it's listed under the definitions of both "up" and "until". And because in your sentence "up until" is followed by a noun phrase (*the fifth grade*), it is used as a **preposition**.

Here are the definitions of ***up until*** in Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[until](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/until)**
>   <sup>[CONJUNCTION, PREPOSITION]</sup>
>   as a **preposition** (followed by a noun): She continued to get a salary until the end of March.
>   as a **conjunction** (connecting two clauses): I stayed there until he arrived.
>   1. happening or done up to a particular point in time, and then stopping
>       *Baker is expected to be here until the end of the week.*
>       *I was employed by a manufacturing company until 1999.*
>       *You'll just have to wait until they call your name.*
>       **up until:** *Up until now, everything in Katherine's life has been taken care of for her.*
>
> **[up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/up)**
>   <sup>adjective, adverb, preposition</sup>
>   [...]
>   **PHRASES**
>   [...]
>   - **up to/until/till something**
>       used for giving the latest time that something can happen, or the end of a period of time
>       *Laura was here up until about 5 minutes ago.*
>       *The building was used as a hospital through the 1960s up to 1972.*
>       *We can make the delivery any time tomorrow up till about 10 pm.*

Answer (score 1):

*all the way* is used as an idiom there.

> [all the way (idiom)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/all+the+way#way_1__208) - during the whole period of time.

*up* probably refers to *the top rank/degree in smartness* among other pupils (until fifth grade).

Comment: Real examples of "all the way up until" from the internet: *"We were together **all the way up until** the last couple of days before the birth."  "Flights can be booked now **all the way up until** 11/11/14."*  You can see based on these, I think, that *up* doesn't have the meaning you suggest.  I'm having trouble putting into words exactly what it **does** mean, however...

Answer (score 0):

All the way up has been already explained up there. But, to make things simpler, ALL THE WAY UP (UNTIL)  is a long way of saying UNTIL.

Example:

> He was top of his class all the way up (until) grade 9.

is the same as

> He was top of his class UNTIL grade 9.